using ip address connect frontend (next.js) and backend (Laravel) in single pc
Thank you for taking time to read my question. i have frontend (next.js) project and backend (Laravel) project and i have to connect and test both in in single one pc how to do the setup please help
i try this like changed - APP_URL in laravel and changed NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL= ,
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_BASE_URL= in next.js env file and my frontend and backend maybe  connected but main problem is API is working , but login , follow , unfollow , update , delete , nothing is not working .
how to do?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Download HERD https://herd.laravel.com .  This is a one stop shop for setting up local dev hosting for Laravel applications
